# Sscanf displays random characters

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following code. I omit the headers.

```
char teacher[1024];
    char subject[1024];
    sscanf(data,"teacher=%s&subject=%s",teacher,subject);
    puts(teacher);
    puts(subject);
```

Why do the code output random, unknown characters like `Xè|·Ïº¿`? What could be the problem? Is it with the `%s`? Thanks!

Comment: What's the `data` string?

Comment: `teacher=Smith&subject=Physics`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `sscanf` did not find any data to put in the `teacher` and/or `subject`, so they are left uninitialized. You should initialize them, and add code that ensures that `sscanf` got both of them set, like this:

```
char teacher[1024] = "";
char subject[1024] = "";
if (sscanf(data,"teacher=%s&subject=%s",teacher,subject) == 2) {
    puts(teacher);
    puts(subject);
} else {
    printf("Error reading teacher and subject.\n");
}
```

To fix, change the first `%s` for `%[^&]`, like this:

```
sscanf(data,"teacher=%[^&]&subject=%s",teacher,subject);
```

This would make `sscanf` stop reading the first string when it reaches the `&` sign.

Comment: +1, though your error condition seems to be flipped (ie. `!= 2` for success instead of failure)

Comment: It doesn't give any output. By the way, the data string is from an HTML form which method is `GET`.

Comment: @JKTA That's because I flipped my condition (it's fixed now). Here is a [link to a working demo](http://ideone.com/laFXJS) of the change.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It still doesn't provide any output Would you mind if I edit the question and post the html and c source code?

Comment: @JKTA That's strange. Did you look at the demo?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, it seems fine. By the way, this is a combination of an html form with checkboxes and text. Whenver I click on one of the three checkboxes, it displays the wrong output. But when I leave all of them unchecked, it displays the correct output. But thanks, your solution worked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35702/discussion-between-jkta-and-dasblinkenlight)

Comment: can you me give a link discussing `string formats` to be passed on `sscanf()`? tnx

Comment: @mr5 [cppreference has a nice table with the codes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).